# objective-c sscanf from NSData

Tags: objective-c, bit-shift, scanf

I have a BTLE device which is sending me bytes, some of which I need to compose into a 32 bit signed int, shift around, then interpret.   I'm using xcode 6.1.

The problem I'm having is in simply converting the bytes to int32_t using sscanf which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.   I'm not an obj-c expert, not sure if this is the right way to do this at all, was using strtol which similarly wasn't working.

The entire function is below:

```
- (double) parseMV2: (NSData*) data {
  NSData* slicedData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
  const char *bytes = [slicedData bytes];
  int32_t value;
  double mV = 0;

  int sscanf_result = sscanf(bytes, "%4x", &value);

  if (1 == sscanf_result) {
    value <<= 3; // discard the 3 most significant bits as they are not part of the value this also brings the sign bit to the most significant bit position.
    value >>= 8; // discard the 5 least significant bits as they are below the noise levels.
    mV = ((double)value)*2048.0/16777216.0; // Convert to mV
  } else {
    NSLog(@" sscanf failed to read bytes %4x (result = %d)", (int32_t) bytes, sscanf_result);
  }

  NSLog(@"     mV2 = %f (bytes = %x", mV, (uint) bytes);
  NSLog(@"----------------------------------");

  return mV;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint after the sscanf, sometimes value is set to the correct interpretation of the bytes but very often it is just set to zero.   Here is some output from llvm:

```
(lldb) print bytes
(const char *) $3 = 0x17ecceb8 "+\333\x91"
(lldb) print value
(int32_t) $4 = 0
```

Here is another example where sscanf again returns 0 but value is not 0 (don't get this since I thought sscanf returns the number of variables it actually assigns to):

```
(lldb) print bytes
(const char *) $6 = 0x176db558 ")Z\x19x"
(lldb) print value
(int32_t) $7 = 383772
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are getting back text. isn't it possible that you are getting raw data (in which case you don't need `scanf()` at all)? Also, shifting into the sign bit is undefined behavior.

Comment: First NSLog the received data. There is no reason to use scan, just use  pointer into the data, cast and access.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant you mean just do this: 
  int32_t value = (int32_t) bytes;   I had thought that the bytes were hex encoded but now I'm not sure, I think the sender is just slicing an int into bytes and sending them over so you might be right.

Comment: @eagspoo no, that will convert the pointer to an integer, whereas you want the integer residing at that address.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant like this?
  int32_t value = (int32_t) &bytes;

Comment: Bytes are not encoded, they are just eight bits (these days), they may be interpreted in may ways, one of which is hex, another is a string or even octal and bits. How they are displayed is just the display function used.

Comment: @eagspoo no, that's even farther. that will convert the address of the pointer to an integer. *Think about it!* `int32_t value = *(int32_t *)[data bytes];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sscanf` is for reading from a C-string but you don't have a C-string. You have a sequence of bytes.

Try it this way:

```
NSData* slicedData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
const uint8_t *bytes = [slicedData bytes];
int32_t value;
memcpy(&value, bytes, 4);
```

And as pointed out by Ken, an even easier way would be:

```
int32_t value;
[data getBytes:&value range:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
```

You may also have to worry about byte ordering depending on how the data was created. You may need to add:

```
value = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(value); // or CFSwapInt32LittleToHost
```

Comment: This is roughly the right approach, but why not use `-[NSData getBytes:range:]` instead of making a slice and then using `memcpy()`? `[data getBytes:&value range:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];`

Comment: @KenThomases Good catch. I overlooked that more direct approach. I updated my answer to include that solution. Thanks.